# How to understand the phrase "going to meet."

Tags: meaning

How can I understand the phrase "going to meet"?

> I never claimed to meet the scammer or go to the actual concert. It was the scammer who was making the claims. That we all was **going to meet** the actor and meet at his concert.

What does "going to meet" in that sentence mean? Can it mean the scammer makes the person say that she communicated with the actor?

Comment: It just says this is that the scammer claimed they were going to meet the actor. The writer didn't claim anything in that sentence.

Comment: It should be *we all **were** going to meet*. Is the text from a particular source or did you make it up yourself?

Comment: Is that sentence from some online chatroom??

Answer (score 1):

The punctuation in this excerpt makes it confusing. The period before 'That' is not necessary and actually creates a sentence fragment out of the last part. Take out the period and the meaning is much clearer. Also, the correct plural form of the past tense of 'to be' is 'were'

> I never claimed to meet the scammer or go to the actual concert. It was the scammer who was making the claims that we all were going to meet the actor and meet at his concert.

The scammer made the claims that the people had plans to meet the actor and meet each other at his concert. The narrator is saying that the narrator did not actually meet the actor or go to the concert, in spite of what the scammer claimed.

Answer (score 0):

The statement means that the scammer said they had plans of meeting at the concert. It does not say whether they actually did meet or not.

"I was going to meet" generally means you had plans to meet someone, but for some reason this meeting never took place. (Because someone cancelled the meeting).